# selenium find child's child elements

Tags: xpath, selenium, element, parent-child, nested

I have following html like:

```
<form name="form1">
  <input name="a" ...>
  <input name="b" ...>
  ...
  <div><span><select name="c">...</select></span></div>
</form>
```

I would like to find out all elements within the form element. First I use `findElement()` to get the form element `form1`, then use `form1.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@name]"))` to get all its children having attribute `name`. However, for the `select` element, since it's grand-grand child of `form1`, how can I get it as well?

Is there a way to find all elements containing attribute `name` (not only child elements, but also child's child's child...) within `form1`?

Thanks!

Comment: What you already have should work since it's not just finding children, but any descendants nested at any level.

Comment: But when I run it, I only get the children elements, not all descendants.@BoltClock'saUnicorn

Comment: Thanks@BoltClock'saUnicorn Yes, you're right. I made a mistake because in google page, I think they use `<input type="select">` to express the select element while the source code displayed as `<select>`. That causes me thought it didn't get all descendants.

Answer (score 17):

if you want to get an WebElement by xpath, and so get child of it... you may use `webElement.findElement(By.xpath("./*"))` ... this "." before the "/" makes the magic, you'll need it to get only the children of the webElement...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to find the form element? If not, then you can do it in one select statement using css or xpath.

The css would be 'form[name="form1"] [name]'

Note the space between the closing and opening brackets.

You would use this selector with FindElement on the driver object rather than finding the form first.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the descendant:: as described in this post.

http://hedleyproctor.com/2011/05/tutorial-writing-xpath-selectors-for-selenium-tests/

Here are a few examples from the article:

```
//div[h3/text()='Credit Card']/descendant::*
//div[h3/text()='Credit Card']/descendant::input[@id='cardNumber']
//div[*/text()='Credit Card']/descendant::input[@id='cardNumber']



  webDriver.findElement(
     By.xpath("//div[*/text()='Credit Card']/descendant::input[@id='cardNumber']")
  ).sendKeys("1234123412341234");
```