# Selenium get only child elements from current parent

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get data from an HTML like this:

```html
<div>
  <h4 id='id1'>...</h4>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <h4 id='id2'>...</h4>
  <ul> ... </ul>
</div>
```

The goal is to get the `<li>` values from every `<h4>`. To get this I've tried something like this:

```py
divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div//h4[starts-with(@id,'id_')]")
for h4 in divs:
    title = h4.text
    # Get <li> from each div
    for value in h4._parent.find_elements_by_tag_name('li'): #<-- It gives me all <li> in the page
        # TODO ...
```

Here I'm trying to get all `<h4>` tags and then go to the parent (the `<div>`) and find the `<li>` tags existing only in that parent. But I retrieve all `<li>` tags.

I've searched over the internet and I've found a couple of question in StackOverflow like [Get child element using xpath selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66166860/13464279) or [selenium find child's child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20216541/13464279) where it says to set the context, so I've tried this:

```py
for value in h4._parent.find_elements_by_xpath('.//li'):
                                                 ^
```

But it gives me the same numbers of elements.

So, I'm misunderstanding something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//div[./h4[starts-with(@id,'id')]]//li
```

To get all li's of all div that contains an element h4 with a certain id starting try this.

//div[./h4] basically means div with h4 element inside 1 layer deep.

Answer (score 0):

[Arendeep question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71057208/13464279) is ok and it worked for me, but also I've noticed the problem I was having.

The element `_parent` seems to be the web page, not the parent element. And this is why the method `find_element` was getting all `<li>` tags from the page.

I can use accepted answer or also:

```py
parent = h4.find_element_by_xpath('..')
for value in parent.find_elements_by_tag_name('li'):
    # TODO
```

Where the xpath `('..')` return the parent element.

This way gives me only child from the current element (maybe is an answer more accurate) but accepted answer also works on my scenario where I want all `<li>` tags dependant from the `<h4>`.

By the way I haven't found docs about `_parent`.